# POST form while in an rselenium session to grab json

Tags: r, rvest, httr, rselenium

I'm able to run an rselenium remote driver to grab data from a private (password) secured website. This requires finding the right xpath or css selector and doing a lot of text cleaning / grep'ing of text since the data is not in table format. In looking at the network tab recently, I found a `Fetch/XHR` document that has the json file with all the source data. However, after many hours of searching and reading up on how to make a POST while in an rselenium session (to grab the json file) I'm coming up empty. Also, I'm unable to use `rvest::session` because I keep getting a `Unknown http status code: 464` code when I try to initiate a session and this is why I'm resorting to using rselenium. Unfortunately, because this is a private website, I'm not able to share the address or any other information besides a screenshot of the network tab payload. I'm hoping this is enough information for someone to start pointing me in the right direction.

My question is: once I'm successfully logged in to a session via rselenium web driver, how can I make a POST to grab a json file with the given request headers?

[image: Source page Network tab]

Comment: Through network tab you can copy that POST request as *fetch*, it might be a good base for a Javascript snippet that you could run through `executeScript()`  . Difficult to suggest something more concrete here. Or maybe copy that request as a `cURL` and see what happens if you convert it to `httr` ( https://curlconverter.com/r/ ) or `httr2` (`httr2::curl_translate()`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll give those a try. I know it's difficult to help since I can't share the username and password. It also makes it difficult for me to figure out why I keep getting a 464 error with both `rvest` and `requests` in python because that error is very non descript and I'm not finding much on it when I search.

Comment: I was able to get a `cURL` script generated from the link you provided but the `status_code` returned 464 again.

Comment: Have you tried fetching it with javascript in your browser, within the current session though js console (copy request as fetch is a good start, though may not be complete) ? Perhaps its payload or header values are only good for a single request or it's part of a mutli-request sequence.

Comment: @margusl I have not. I tried using `executeScript` but I wasn't doing it correctly I think. I need to read up on it a bit more on to properly format the `fetch` to run in `executeScript`.